# Convert dataframe to be used in ggplot barchart

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks something like this:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Region = rep(1:14, each=112),
  Job = rpois(112*14, 0.7)
)
```

And the following code puts it into a dataframe that I could use to plot the frequencies on a bar chart, for each region using ggplot and facet_wrap:

```
DF1 = data.frame(table(subset(df, Region == 1)$Jobs))
DF2 = data.frame(table(subset(df, Region == 2)$Jobs)) 
.
.
.
DF14 = data.frame(table(subset(df, Region == 14)$Jobs))

df1 <- do.call("rbind", list(DF1, DF2, ... ,DF14))

df1$Region <- c(rep('Region 1',nrow(DF1)),
                rep('Region 2',nrow(DF2)),
                            .
                            .
                            .
                rep('Region 14',nrow(DF14))  )
```

Is there a more efficient generalizable method for doing this?

Comment: `dplyr::count(df, Region, Job)`

Comment: As Shah suggests, the dplyr package is really suitable for these kind of transformations, you can combine them using pipes: df %>% group_by(Region, Jobs) %>% summarise(Freq=n())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is absolutely no need to do all that subsetting and then combining everything back together.

Your data in `df` is already in the right format, you can just do:

```r
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(
  Region = rep(1:14, each=112),
  Job = rpois(112*14, 0.7)
)
ggplot(df, aes(Job)) +
  geom_bar() +
  facet_wrap(~ as.factor(Region))
```

[image]

Which I guess is what you were aiming for?

Comment: Yes it is, thank you, I didn't realise ggplot worked like that!